# is it possible to slide two range input elements from one, in short inline event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to save in code space. Is there a short code I can enter in the 'onchange' inline to have the two range elements affect each other by moving just one of them?

```html
<form onchange="">
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeA" name="rangeA" min="-10" max="10">
</form>

<form onchange="">
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeB" name="rangeB" min="-10" max="10">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want the onchange to do exactly to both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply attach the same event handler to both forms. the event handler will simply check which form's range has changed, and will change the other form's range accordingly. you could theoretically have hundreds of those forms with ranges, and one of them will change the rest using this same event handler:

```js
//on dom ready
$(function() {
  //attach a change event listener to all forms
  $("form").on("change", function() {
    //for each of those forms do the following on change:

    //assign a $currForm to point at the current form
    $currForm = $(this);
    //get a list of all other forms and change their range
    //when the range of the current form changes
    $("form").filter(function() {
      //compares all forms with the current one and returns the others
      return $(this) != $currForm;
    }).children("input[type=range]").val($currForm.children("input[type=range]").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeA" name="rangeA" min="-10" max="10">
</form>

<form>
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeB" name="rangeB" min="-10" max="10">
</form>
<form>
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeC" name="rangeC" min="-10" max="10">
</form>
<form>
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeD" name="rangeD" min="-10" max="10">
</form>
<form>
  <input type="range" value="0" id="rangeE" name="rangeE" min="-10" max="10">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this not cause an infinite recursive call to onchange event?

Comment: @IsraelGav the jQuery `.val()` does not trigger an `onchange` event :)